Circular Hedge Maze
This is a fun Puzzle I recently made by myself which I think is a new one for you all. Try to solve it.

Rules

You can select and start from any of the positions A, B, C, D, E one at a time.

There are a total of six circular paths in the hedge maze. Each path has some defined points 1-6 increasing from inner to outer
paths respectively.

You will try to solve the same maze from all the 5 positions (A, B, C, D, E) one at a time.

You have to pass exactly through all of the 10 doors in any order to get some points otherwise you will get zero points even if you passed 9 or less doors in total.

Each time your final score will be determined by in which path you finish. For example, if you start from position A, you pass through all the 10 doors and passed the last door which was in path three so you will get 3 points because you finished in path three.

You have to get a total sum of 17 points at which you win the maze instantly. For example, you get 4 points from position A, 2 from B and 5 from C, 5 from D and 1 from E, so 4+2+5+5+1 = 17 points will win you the maze.

You cannot cross the Hedge or through the same route more than once.

Each time you solve a maze, so when you start from the next position the maze will be renewed, meaning all the routes are cleared so you can solve the maze again.

You can go outside of the maze at any point.

It's not necessary to go outside of the maze after you pass all the 10 doors.

You cannot have intersections of routes.




Welcome to PSE! I think this puzzle needs some further clarifications. There are outer holes here, does this mean 1) "finishing the maze" implies actually going out of it at the end (rather than just stopping at the last door) or 2) you are allowed to go outside at any point? 3) Can an intersection be passed twice, as long as the two paths do not cross each others circular paths? I think I have a solution if 1) is false, 2) is true and 3) is false, but I'm not sure I'm operating under the intended ruleset.

@LukasRotter No its not necessary to go out of the maze at the end. You can finish anywhere you just pass the 10 doors in any order.  Intersections of routes are also not allowed.

@LukasRotter yes and you can go outside the maze at any point

Solution:

 

Solving Process:

 There is no way for E to pass all outer doors before going deeper, so if E is involved its score must be 6. For B it is impossible to find a start that doesn't immediately make it invalid, same for D. So only A, C and E=6 can be used, therefore [A,C] is [5,6] in some order. Since all of them need to enter and exit the middle section of the maze and each ring only has 2 entrances, we can force a path for each of them and solve from there.


Very good to see that you found the solution. This is the only solution for the puzzle. I appreciate you solved my puzzle. Just wanted to take a feedback on this puzzle from you. Was it too hard? Did you find it interesting, fun and challenging or unique. Thanks.

@UnknownCreater Overall a nice little puzzle! I liked the logic that is involved here, which differentiates it from being a normal path-finding exercise. It definitely wasn't too hard, I think the difficulty level is good for a puzzle that is supposed to take a few minutes. BTW, please consider accepting this answer if it solved the puzzle appropriately.

Thankyou. I appreciate it very much. Also accepted your answer as it was the best solution.
